# Blocking connection flood

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

**Problem:**

Assuming my application gets flooded with connection attempts (attempted DDoS attack) and I want to ignore any traffic and connection attempts from some endpoint from now on, what would be the best place to filter?

**Use Case:**

In my application I'm using an System.Net.TcpListener to listen for incoming connections.
My naive approach would be to just accept all connections, check the endpoint and then possibly close the connection instantly.

Something tells me that that can't be very efficient. Even just the creation of the TcpClient while accepting alone in my application will consume resources.

So what can I do to reliably reject connections from some endpoint/ip while expending minimal resources to do so on Windows? What about the same situation on Linux systems?

On Linux there's "iptables", is that as efficient as it gets?
And on Windows one could use the built-in firewall system.

Are there any other ways to block connections from an ip in software that might be even more efficient? If so what are those?

**Hardware Firewalls:**

Please do not try to mention hardware firewalls and filters. I am aware of them and know they are made for this purpose, but this question is explicitly about the software side of things.

Comment: There aren't more efficient things than IPTables or the integrated windows firewall, they work at O.S. level so it's the most effective you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something tells me that that can't be very efficient. Even just the
>   creation of the TcpClient while accepting alone in my application will
>   consume resources.

You're right. Once the traffic reaches your application, your machine has already invested quite a lot of resources into opening the newly formed session. At the very least, you've used up network resources, plus the operating system allocated buffers and various data structures for the new socket.

> So what can I do to reliably reject connections from some endpoint/ip
>   while expending minimal resources to do so on Windows? What about the
>   same situation on Linux systems?

You've mentioned the answer in your own question - use firewalls. If not hardware firewalls, then software ones. If you're flooded from specific, known IP addresses or the malicious traffic has some other attribute that you can define a firewall rule for, do it. On windows you can use the regular windows firewall, on linux - simply use Iptables. Both would be much more efficient than application level filtering.

You might also want to consider using [Syn Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies), which sometimes have to be explicitly enabled. They're effective against some types of DDos attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block requests based on IP address and/or port before they reach your application receives it by means of an application server or as the return from accept system call, the you need to stop those request at the operating system level. It would be a solution like iptables in Linux or Windows firewall as you mentioned. Once your application receives a request, the three-way handshake occurred before return from accept system call and the whole request was read.

If you want to block requests based on content probably you have to do it in your application if you don't want to have a layer 5 or 7 router.

Consider there are different types of DDoS attacks, some create half-connections at TCP layer interrupting the TCP three-way handshake and some send actual requests that look valid and they just consume resources of CPU, bandwidth, disk, DB connections, etc. But in general it is impossible to prevent DDoS with a blacklist of IP addresses because the attackers have a huge range of addresses to spoof.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a second program monitoring your network, and sort of acting like a filter? Have it listen in on the ports you are using, and have it time the amount of time between connections from the IP address and check the requests for content. If the connections from the address exceed a threshold, then blacklist the user. Also, you can monitor the average request rate for times of day and get an average. If the request count is extremely high, it almost certainly is a DDOS and you should lower the threshold for time between connection request from a IP address to much stricter constraints. Note: this is strictly scanning for incoming connections: checking incoming connections does not consume system resources as if you were starting a socket to accept the connection.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem during DDOS Attacking , and to solve this problem, I implemented a method that when the TCPlistener crashes, the system rebuilds it and this snake greatly increases the stability of the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple application for windows systems.
Written in C#, source code available. This application is listenning tcp ports and group by ip addresses, if an ip address have more than the count which is set on program then it creates windows firewall command.
run firewall commmands, thats it.

https://github.com/devrimcelik/IPBlock-DDos

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).